# how to check quota for Azure spot VMs vCPU's using Python Azure SDK?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-python-sdk

I was automating quota check in Azure using Python SDK for compute product(mainly VM, vCPU,scaleset,etc). The Code written displays usage,alloted quota for all resources except spot vCPU's. Even CLI command given in Microsoft Documentation doesn't display spot vCPU usage.
Python code-

```
from os import environ

from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.monitor import MonitorClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
subscription_id = environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"]
credentials     #add token credentials 
y=compute_client.usage.list('centralindia')
for i in y:
    print(i.name.value,i.limit,i.current_value)
```

CLI command-

```
az vm list-usage -l westus
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [how can we check azure resource quota using python SDK?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9095cc28-36d7-45f4-b235-6864e5ef771c/how-can-we-check-azure-resource-quota-using-python-sdk?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows), [compute_test.py](https://github.com/gbowerman/azurerm/blob/main/test/compute_test.py#:~:text=%23%20get%20compute%20usage,%3E%200) and [Request an increase for spot vCPU quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/spot-quota)

Comment: Thank You @DeepDave-MT . Low priority cores are also included in output with this code.